# Count Character Consecutively in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to write a method that returns the number of times char c first appears consecutively in s, even if it's a single occurrence of the character. Even spaces break the consecutive count. So the string "I'm bad at programming." should only return 1, if char c was 'a'.

The code below compiles but doesn't print the correct answers. Just something to show my general logic when it comes to approaching this problem.

```
public class WordCount
{
  public int countRun( String s, char c )
  {
    int counter = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    /*There should be other conditions here that checks for first
      appearance consecutively. I've tried my fair share, but no
      luck on getting correct results.*/
    {
      if( s.charAt(i) == c )
      {
        counter += 1;
      }
    }
    return counter;
  }

  public static void main( String args[] )
  {
    WordCount x = new WordCount();
    System.out.println( x.countRun( "Add dog", 'd' ) ); //should return 2
    System.out.println( x.countRun( "Add dog", 'D' ) ); //should return 0
    System.out.println( x.countRun( "Hope you're happy", 'p' )); //should return 1
    System.out.println( x.countRun( "CCCCCcccC", 'C' )); //should return 5
  }
}
```

I just need a few pointers (logic-wise or code). Maybe there's a method for Strings that I've never seen before that could make my program much simpler. I have very limited knowledge in programming and in Java.

EDIT: For anyone wondering if this is part of some homework assignment or whatnot, this was a question from a very old midterm. I got it wrong but for some reason but never bothered to ask for the correct answer at the time. I looked at it today and wanted to see if I knew the answer. Looks like I don't.

Comment: What should `("This is Paris", P)` return ?

Comment: what is the current output ?

Comment: Shouldn't `countRun("Hope you're happy", 'p')` return `2`, not `1`?

Comment: Clearly there's nothing here that looks only for consecutive characters. All this code does is count the total number of times the specified character appears.

Comment: What about using: `int charCount = StringUtils.CountMatches(str, ch);`?

Comment: @Vulcan I'm trying to write a method that returns the number of times char c first appears consecutively in s, **even if it's a single occurrence of the character**

Comment: @PLB `StringUtils` on a midterm? No.

Comment: @Vulcan - "hope" has one p... you never should count the double p in "happy".

Comment: @Adarsh Thanks, I missed that it should only count the *first* series.

Comment: @Adarsh ("This is Paris", P) should return 1.

Comment: @Shivan Raptor The current code only counts the occurrence of the char in the string.

Comment: @Vulcan ("Hope you're happy", 'p') returns 1 because the char after the first p isn't 'p'. The method should stop incrementing the count if the next char doesn't match the given char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a flag, and break out of the loop when you have found one matching character, then find "anything else". Maybe not the most compact or elegant, but true to the original code. Tested, and produces 2,0,1,5 as expected.

```
public int countRun( String s, char c )
  {
    int counter = 0;
    boolean foundOne = false;
    for( int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
      if( s.charAt(i) == c )
      {
        counter += 1;
        foundOne = true;
      }
      else {
        if(foundOne) break;
      }
    }
    return counter;
  }
```

It occurs to me that `counter>0` is an equivalent condition to `foundOne==true`; that would allow you to simplify the code to:

```
public int countRun( String s, char c )
  {
    int counter = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
      if( s.charAt(i) == c )  counter++;
      else if(counter>0) break;
    }
    return counter;
  }
```

The logic is a tiny bit harder to follow this way, as the variable name `foundOne` is self-documenting. But per other posts, "small is beautiful" too...

Comment: `if (foundOne)`? `foundOne` is an `int`, that if-statement will not compile.  In Java, you'll need to use a boolean rather than a 0-1 integer.

Comment: Just change `foundOne` to be a boolean - I detect a long habit with more-forgiving languages here `:)`

Comment: @Vulcan : Yes... sorry I'm a C guy (as Matt Ball detected). Fixed it to `foundOne==1`.

Comment: No, seriously, just use a boolean. It's always a WTF to use a number for a value of a binary state.

Comment: I think this solves it all. Given my level of knowledge, this is probably what my graders were looking for. Thanks @Floris!

Comment: Happy to help Bob. One day you will prefer @Bohemian's high density answer... but not in your first midterm!

Comment: @MattBall - not only am I a "C guy", I'm an "OLD" C guy. When I learned this stuff there was no such thing as a bool (or boolean) type. Rather than look it up as I switch between languages (is it `True` or `true` or `TRUE`? `bool` or `boolean` or `Boolean`?...), I tend stick with what I know. But I'll go ahead and correct my errant ways now.

Answer (score 7):

You could do it in one line:

```
int result = s.replaceFirst(".*?(" + c + "+).*", "$1").length();
```

This code uses regex to essentially extract the part of `s` that is the first contiguous occurrences of  `c`, then gets the length of that.

This will also work for *no* occurrences, yielding zero.

See [live demo](http://ideone.com/ocOs64).

Comment: to me, this seems to not be efficient enough to make up for its lack of readability.

Comment: Clever answer, but from the sound of the question, I wouldn't think that regex would have been taught before the OP's midterm.  +1 regardless.

Comment: @Vulcan I confess that "showing off" with terse code is a weakness of mine. Nevertheless, this is how I would do it. I firmly believe that less code is good (as long as it remains readable. I would argue that this single line is at least as readable as fathoming the many lines of OP's code.. Plus I'm claiming a high degree of difficulty for typing this in on my iPhone :)

Comment: +1 and a nomination for the Iridium award. Or Osmium if you prefer.

Comment: @HernánEche [works now](http://ideone.com/ocOs64). It was missing a `?` to make the initial quantifier *reluctant*. Thanks for picking up the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using assci array counter

```
 public static int countRun(String s, char c) {
    int[] counts = new int[256];
    int count = 0;
    char currChar;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        currChar = s.charAt(i);
        if (currChar == c) {// match
            counts[c]++;
        } else if (Character.isSpaceChar(currChar)) {
            counts[c] = 0;// reset counter for c
        } else {// no match
            if (counts[c] > 0) {// return accumulated counts if you have
                count = counts[c];
                return count;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A3B2C1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "AAABBC";
        
        s = s + '#';//dummy char to consider the last char 'C' in the string
        
        //without using charAt()
        int count = 1;
        String n="";
        int i=0;
        
        StringBuffer bf = new StringBuffer();
        char c[] = s.toCharArray();
        
        for(i=0;i< c.length-1;i++)
        {
            if(c[i] == c[i+1])
            {
                count++;
            } 
            else 
            {
                n = c[i] +""+count;
                bf.append(n);
                count=1;
            }
        }   
        System.out.println("Output: "+bf);//prints-->> Output: A3B2C1
    }
}
```